# Facebook like button is not display in my web page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am using twitter bootstrap. i added the code for facebook like button but that is not display for my web page.

```
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id))
                    return;
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://ringee.in"data-layout="standard" data-action="like"data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook icons and like buttons are hidden by adblockers.

If you use one try to disable it on your page and see if it appears.

Comment: now i disabled my adblocker then also button dosen't visible

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there has to be a space before the data-layout (after the href value)?

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://ringee.in" data-layout="standard" data-action="like"data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but still now it's not working